# String parameter as lockable resources label in jenkins

Tags: jenkins, groovy, jenkins-plugins

I am trying to setup a job with the use of lockable resources.
My job is parameterized and one of the String parameters is parameter 'ENVIRONMENT'.

I would like to use this parameter as groovy expression label for lockable resources plugin, i.e.:

```
groovy:resourceLabels.contains(${ENVIRONMENT})
```

but the expression is not being evaluated.

Is there a way to make it evaluate String parameter like this?

Answer (score 0):

I'm not sure it's the only problem, but it looks like double-quotes are missing

```
groovy:resourceLabels.contains("${ENVIRONMENT}")
```

cf [groovy gstring](http://docs.groovy-lang.org/latest/html/documentation/index.html#_double_quoted_string)

Answer (score 0):

Job Parameters are more correctly referenced from the `params` object:
With this the groovy string interpolation is not required,

```
groovy:resourceLabels.contains(params.ENVIRONMENT)
```